# How can I sort a std::list with case sensitive elements?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl

This is my current code:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::list;

int main()
{
    list <string> list_;
    list_.push_back("C");
    list_.push_back("a");
    list_.push_back("b");

    list_.sort();
}
```

Does the `sort()` function sort the elements according to their character codes? I want the result here to be `a b C` after the sorting is done.

Comment: If all you need is single characters, I highly suggest reducing some bloat by using `char` instead of `std::string`. Comparing will be much easier as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default comparator (`<`) using the default `char_traits< char >` will sort your list as `C a b`.

See [list::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/).

In order to achieve the desired order `a b C` you can either:

1. compose your list of `string` types with [custom `char_traits`](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/string/icstring.hpp.html), *or*
2. provide an instance of a custom string comparator to `sort`, e.g.

   ```
   bool istring_less(const string& lhs, const string& rhs) {
     string::const_iterator \
       lb = lhs.begin(), le = lhs.end(),
       rb = rhs.begin(), re = rhs.end();
     const char lc, rc;
     for ( ; lb != le && rb != re; ++lb, ++rb) {
       lc = tolower(*lb);
       rc = tolower(*rb);
       if (*lc < *rc) return true;
       if (*lc > *rc) return false;
     }
     // if rhs is longer than lhs then lhs<rhs
     return (rb != re);
   }
   ...
   list.sort(istring_less);
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Case-insensitive character comparisons are tricky if you want to support characters from other languages. That's why it's a good idea to do them in a locale-sensible manner:

```
struct char_iless 
: public std::binary_function<char, char, bool>
{
    std::locale loc;

    char_iless(std::locale const & loc=std::locale()) : loc(loc) 
    {
    }

    bool operator()(char a, char b) const
    {
        return std::tolower(a, loc) < std::tolower(b, loc);
    }
};
```

This is how you use this class to compare two chars:

```
char_iless('a', 'b', my_locale);
```

Just use `std::locale()` as `my_locale` if you want to use the one that's set as default.

If you can use Boost then there is am `is_iless` functor in the String Algorithms library which does the same thing.

Extending this from comparing chars to strings is easy thanks to `std::lexicographical_compare`:

```
struct str_iless 
: public std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, bool>
{
    std::locale loc;

    str_iless(std::locale const & loc=std::locale()) : loc(loc) 
    {
    }

    bool operator()(std::string const & a, std::string const & b) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(
            a.begin(), a.end(),
            b.begin(), b.end(),  
            char_iless(loc)
        );
    }
};
```

Now you have all that it's required to solve your problem:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list;
    list.push_back("C");
    list.push_back("a");
    list.push_back("b");

    // Sort using default locale
    list.sort(str_iless());  

    // Sort using French locale 
    // (warning: this locale format string is MS specific)
    std::locale loc("French_France.1252");
    list.sort(str_iless(loc));
}
```

Comment: +1, much cleaner comparison operator than the hand coded version in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are what I consider to be some cleaner and one significantly faster alternative:

```
#include    <string>
#include    <cstring>
#include    <iostream>
#include    <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using std::string;
using std::list;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using namespace boost::algorithm;

// recommended in Meyers, Effective STL when internationalization and embedded
// NULLs aren't an issue.  Much faster than the STL or Boost lex versions.
struct ciLessLibC : public std::binary_function<string, string, bool> {
    bool operator()(const string &lhs, const string &rhs) const {
        return strcasecmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str()) < 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
};

// If you need sorting according to the default system local
struct ciLessBoost : std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, bool>
{
    bool operator() (const std::string & s1, const std::string & s2) const {
        return lexicographical_compare(s1, s2, is_iless());
    }
};

int main(void) {
    list <string> list_;
    list_.push_back("C");
    list_.push_back("a");
    list_.push_back("b");

    list_.sort(ciLessLibC());
    list_.sort(ciLessBoost());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes

[you can check the following code to use a custom comparator](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_using_a_custom_comparator)

Answer (score 0):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparator function/struct:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<string> list_;
    list_.emplace_back("C");
    list_.emplace_back("a");
    list_.emplace_back("b");

    list_.sort([](const string& a, const string& b) {
        return (strcasecmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) < 0);
    });

    for (auto const &str : list_)
        cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> a
>   b
>   C

Note: The function [`strcasecmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcasecmp.html) (as also suggested in the answer by @RobertS.Barnes) is not in the C++ standard and, therefore, not available on every system. For example, if you are using Visual Studio, you could use [`_stricmp()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx) instead.

If internationalization is an issue for you, then you can apply a locale as @Manuel did in his answer.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/vFNZoe)