# How to sort std::list<..>

Tags: c++

i have a list of Elemtents of a custom type:

```
std::list<CDataTransferElement*> m_list;
```

The class is defined like this:

```
    class CDataTransferElement
{
public:
    CDataTransferElement(void);
    ~CDataTransferElement(void);

    CString Name;
    double PercentValue;
    double MOLValue;
    int PhaseIndex;

};
```

I have x Items in the m_list Object, that have to be sorted by the PhaseIndex Variable in a new Object (what type of ever).
In the end i need x lists of the CDataTransferElement Elements where each list has only Elements with the same PhaseIndex.

How do i do that at best?

regards
camelord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your list adding each CDataTransferElement to a new list stored in a map.

```
std::map<int,std::list<CDataTransferElement*> > m;
for( std::list<CDataTransferElement*>::iterator i=m_list.begin(); i!=m_list.end(); ++i)
{
  m[ (*it)->PhaseIndex ].append( (*it) );
}
```

You can then loop over the map to do whatever you like with the new separated lists.

```
for( std::map<int,std::list<CDataTransferElement*> >::iterator it = m.begin();
     it!=m.end();
     ++it )
{
  do_somthing_with_list( it->first, it->second );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the  header

It provides std::sort(std::iterator begin,std::iterator end)

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/sort

Comment: You can provide a custom comparison object. But I think what the OP really wants is to separate the list into several new lists, not sort it.

Comment: `std::sort` requires random access iterators, so it won't work with `std::list`.  `std::list` provides its own `sort()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a custom comparator.  See for example [sort std::list case sensitive elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346714/sort-stdlist-case-sensitive-elements#2346721) .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use std::sort, you can overload the operator < in your class.
I think using vector rather than list is much better if you want random access